# Accessibility and domain names

Tags: wordpress, localhost, raspberry-pi, host, lan

As I understand it, this may not be exactly the correct place to post this question, but I'm not sure where else I would.

Okay, some background. I recently turned my Raspberry Pi into a Wordpress server using Apache2. I have the site working pretty much the way I want it to, and everything is running smoothly. When I went to access it from a network that was *not* my LAN, I found that I could not. I'm not entirely sure why this is, but I was thinking because I do not have a domain name for it? As I am new to this, any explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's wrong, try to add this to your wp-config.php

```
 define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp' );
 define('WP_HOME', WP_SITEURL);
```

Where `'/wp'` should be your own prefix, and if it's in the root directory of apache it should be empty.

Comment: Okay, unless I misunderstood something, I tried and this did not work. Thanks though. :/

Comment: @CoilKid, can you access other sites in your RPi from the WAN?

Comment: Okay, Yes, but I just solved this. I was using incorrect values for the site urls.